# "Бабине літо" - походження даного виразу

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Останні теплі дні осені називають "бабине літо".

В [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE) подається лише визначення даного виразу -  *період теплої та сухої погоди восени пов'язаний зі стійким антициклоном.*

Яке походження має словосполучення "бабине літо"? 
В [фразеологічному словнику](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53393/356001.html) вираз відсутній.  Чи можна даний вираз вважати фразеологізмом?

Comment: [Тут](http://coollingua.blogspot.com/2010/10/blog-post_10.html) (хоч сайт не дуже авторитетний) наводять іншомовні аналоги, через що складається враження, що це міжнародний вираз. Там же наводять версію, що це «пора, коли під осіннім сонцем ще можуть погрітися старі жінки». А в наведеній Вами статті Вікіпедії також висловлюють альтернативну версію, що це не від назви пори отримало назву летюче павутиння, а навпаки (тобто _літо_ від _літати_, а _баба_ — бо павутиння з волоссям асоціюється; ця ж версія є й за моїм посиланням) — хоча навряд, якщо німецькою справді _Altweibersommer_.

Comment: (Хоча теоретично не виключено, що походження цього виразу все-таки інше, просто початковий зміст забувся, а вже після цього німці скалькували цей вираз у слов'ян.)

Answer (score 2):

Цитую статтю із [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BE):

> За однією із версій саме від павутини, що літає, («лето», «літо») та
>   міфологічної Баби походить і назва «Бабине літо».

А **Баба** - це міфічна істота в образі жінки з довгим волоссям, яка убиває або до смерті залоскотує людей, одне з найстародавніших і найбільших божеств у прото-українців, які жили у кам'яну добу та давніх українців палеоліту, неоліту, енеоліту, бронзової доби ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F))).

Також бачимо й інший варіант:

> «Бабське літо» або «бабине» є однією з давніх українських назв місяця
>   вересня. За спостереженнями фольклориста Якова Головацького: «Зовут
>   також сей місяць <вересень> „бабське літо“ для того, що баби свої
>   роботи порают, коноплі отіпают, полотна добілюют, дещо в городах
>   порают і пр.»

А крім того, на тій же Вікіпедії є пояснення аналогічного поняття із німеціької мови "Altweibersommer", тобто "старо-бабине літо":

> Дослідники, що виводять походження поняття з давньоверхньонімецької,
>   вважають його похідним від зовнішнього природного феномену летіння у
>   вересні павутиння, що нагадує сиве жіноче волосся.
>
> Інші вважають секундарне значення знаходиться у значенні «другої
>   молодості» жінки, яка приходить невчасно і триває дуже короткий час.
>   На це пояснення вказують фахівці, які вбачають аналогію у подібних
>   назвах інших діалектів німецької, як наприклад «вдове літо» (нім.
>   Witwesömmerli) в швейцарській німецькій або «дідусеве літо» (нім.
>   Ähnlsummer, Großvatersommer) в баварському діалекті. В
>   північно-німецьких діалектах, навпаки, «бабине літо» часом зветься
>   «дівчачим літом» (нім. Mettjensommer, Mettkensommer).

Також у цьому [джерелі](https://politeka.net/ua/news/497970-babine-lito-chomu-tak-nazivayetsya-i-koli-pochnetsya/) бачимо таке походження цього вислову:

> Згідно з переказами словосполучення «бабине літо» означало пору, коли
>   жінки закінчували роботи в полі і могли трохи відпочити. У цей час
>   жінки відходили від польових робіт і займалися домашніми справами.

І друга версія:

> Також існує інша версія походження «бабиного літа». Згідно древнім
>   забобонам жінки можуть містичним чином повертати назад пори року і
>   всіляко впливати на погоду. У народі кажуть, що «тільки жінка може так
>   зігріти, коли вже майже все втрачено».

Отож, як бачите, версій є дуже багато і важко сказати яка з них 100% вірна, однак я вважаю, що варто дотримуватися найпершого припущення, яке я навів у відповіді.